# JFreeChart drag plot area

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to be able to drag the plot area to be able to move the x-axis across.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly is. Check out [this Java Web Start](http://www.jroller.com/dgilbert/entry/more_interactive_charts) demo. The [XYPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) (for example) supports the `Pannable` interface.

Comment: Cool...this does the trick. chart.getXYPlot().setDomainPannable(true);